# Keycloak 'ExampleDS' in production

Tags: jboss, keycloak

I'm following the guide to set up Keycloak 3.0.0 in HA mode for production with an Oracle DB. I see in the `standalone-ha.xml` file there's a subsystem:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
```

At the bottom of that subsystem section there's a `<default-bindings>` element that refers to an `ExampleDS` datasource:

```
<default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
```

`ExampleDS` is declared to use the h2 driver, which we cannot use in production.

Can I change that `<default-bindings>` element to refer to my Oracle `KeycloakDS` datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add and configure the oracle jdbc driver beforehand and then add the datasource that is needed for keycloak. You can follow the example setup that is stated [here](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/content/server_installation/topics/database.html). What you have seen there with ExampleDS h2 is just the standard example configuration that comes with wildfly by default, so this won't help you as keycloak will complain that there is no KeycloakDS (as stated in the linked tutorial)

Comment: Leaving ExampleDS in the configuration and setting it to use Oracle seemed to work.